# Using the ffmpeg to extract video stream

Tags: video, ffmpeg, hevc

I try to extract the video stream from the [bbb-1920x1080-cfg02.mkv](http://www.libde265.org/hevc-bitstreams/bbb-1920x1080-cfg02.mkv)

The command as follows.

```
ffmpeg -i bbb-1920x1080-cfg02.mkv -map 0:0 -c copy bbb.mkv
```

But the output file can't play with the player(potplayer)

I used the ffmpeg -i bbb.mkv to check the information and there were lots of 
error messages.

```
ffmpeg version N-80680-ga887fbb Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3)
configuration: --enable-vaapi --disable-vda --disable-vdpau --disable-libxcb  --disable-ffplay --disable-ffserver --disable-ffprobe --disable-indev=jack --disable-outdev=sdl --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-gpl --disable-libxcb --disable-libxcb-shm --disable-libxcb-xfixes --disable-libxcb-shape --disable-x11grab
libavutil      55. 26.100 / 55. 26.100
libavcodec     57. 46.100 / 57. 46.100
libavformat    57. 40.101 / 57. 40.101
libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
libavfilter     6. 46.102 /  6. 46.102
libswscale      4.  1.100 /  4.  1.100
libswresample   2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
[hevc @ 0x3a64a60] No start code is found.
[hevc @ 0x3a64a60] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[hevc @ 0x3a64a60] No start code is found.
```

Even I just make a copy of the source file.

```
ffmpeg -i bbb-1920x1080-cfg02.mkv -map 0 -c copy bbb.mkv
```

The output file(bbb.mkv) still can't play with the player(potplayer)
It still has "[hevc @ 0x3a64a60] No start code is found" error.

As the [document](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html) said that it would do notthing but just encapsulate the matroska format.

Is anyone can teach me how to figure out this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll have to use a bitstream filter. Seems like FFmpeg does not write the correct codec tag without it.

```
ffmpeg -i bbb-1920x1080-cfg02.mkv -map 0:0 -c copy -vbsf hevc_mp4toannexb bbb.mkv
```

Comment: Is better to add "-vbsf hevc_mptoannexb" when manipulates with the HEVC stream?

Comment: When stream copying, yes. Shouldn't be needed when encoding.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the ffmpeg solution from Gyan, but it didn't work for me.  I also had to specify the format.  Here is what I did to get just the H.265 bitstream.  Also, I did see that some people suggested setting the output file extension to .bin, but I like h264/h265 as it makes it more clear what kind of bitstream the file contains.

**H.265 to Annex B**

```
ffmpeg -i test.mkv -c:v copy -bsf hevc_mp4toannexb -f hevc test.h265
```

**H.264 to Annex B**

```
ffmpeg -i test.mkv -c:v copy -bsf h264_mp4toannexb -f h264 test.h264
```

*NOTE:  This also works for .mov files and probably for other formats as well.*